# Genetic algorithm for Linear Intersections problem or Overlay of Subdivisions problem

Tags: algorithm, overlay, computational-geometry, genetic-algorithm

I was suggested to create a GA algorithm to solve the problem of linear intersections identification in 2d space. I have been thinking to modify the sweep line algorithm or a similar one (like Bentley Ottman) and create a GA algorithm.
I have been studying the literature and i also came accross "Overlay of Subdivisions" problem which is quite similar, but for multiple layers of data. Not a lot information on that problem and i am struggling to understand the algorithm.
I am now thinking that in the first case a GA optimization is impossible but maybe it is possible for the overlay of subdivisions problem.
Anyone with more experience thinks that this will work or am i looking for the impossible?

Comment: Does "GA algorithm" stand for "genetic algorithm algorithm"?

Comment: In any case, your question is quite dense; I suggest cutting it into several paragraphs, perhaps with a few illustrations of the concepts you mention. Someone might have great insight that you would be interested in, but be off-putted because every single sentence in your post requires knowing a bunch of very specialized keywords. Reading your post is a bit overwhelming. in just a few lines of text without any context: "GA algorithm linear intersections identification 2d space sweep line algorithm Bentley Ottman Overlay of Subdivisions multiple layers of data GA optimization"

Comment: Does the literature have any (successful) examples of applying GA to the subdivisions problem?

Comment: Using a genetic approach to solve a geometric problem that has a relatively simple polynomial-time solution seems a nonsense.

https://perso.uclouvain.be/vincent.legat/documents/meca2170/meca2170-cours3-LineSegment.pdf

Comment: Indeed it sounds like a nonsense to me too now that i have searched the literature in detail and i know roughly how genetic algorithms work. This is probably the reason there is no single example of applying the genetic algorithm to intersection problems.  But this is what i suggested to explore.. unfortunately.